# Create fake UDP traffic

Tags: udp, client-server

I have to write a UDP client.  Unfortunately, the source system is not always available

Is there a simple tool out there that I can use to create a fake UDP server/traffic on my machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) with the -u option to send data over UDP.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create UDP socket and fill it with dummy data?

PS: What do you mean by source system? Do you mean sender? In that case, you can generate localhost UDP socket.